# Magnetic field simulation for "quasi-solenoid" - Where to start?

Tags: python, matlab, electromagnetism

I would kindly ask you which (preferably free) programs / codes do you suggest for the numerical simulation of the problem described below. I am not asking for the full solution, but just want to avoid “reinventing the wheel” as much as possible. I have access to Matlab and Python (Anaconda), which means that I can install programs like Netgen/NGSolve, Salome etc.

For the case of “quasi-solenoid”, through which I put a strong, but short current (discharged from capacitor), I want to calculate the spatial distribution of magnetic and (using the Maxwell–Faraday equation) electric field at the moment of strongest current.
I used the prefix quasi as I want to specify that the distance between the wires and solenoid axis isn’t always constant, but varies quite substantially, though I still believe that I can describe the spatial distribution of wires using some parametric function or something else. Furthermore, though for now this isn’t so relevant, the cross-section of the wire isn’t circular, but rectangular.

Searching through the internet I already found and used some codes, such as https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50434-biot-savart-magnetic-toolbox, but they do not cover everything that is relevant for me. For example, I doubt that we can apply the Biot-Savart law, which this code uses, for my case.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: May be this post could be useful  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/513834/current-density-in-a-3d-loop-discretising-a-model/515657#515657

Comment: Before simulating anything, one should be fully clear on the mathematical model; it seems to me that the author is not quite sure on what equations to solve here.

Comment: The main issue I am having is regarding the validity of Biot-Savart law for my case. If I am not mistaken, this law is derived from Ampère's circuital law, while the so-called Maxwell addition is ignored (the term containing time derivative of electric field). From what I calculated, it seems that the same can be done in my case. However, what bothers me is the fact that the Biot-Savart law is defined as an equation describing the magnetic field generated by a constant electric current.

Comment: Yes, you are right - the Biot-Savart law is for steady state only. But if the time variation is slow then it is still close to the steady state situation. How did you estimate the relative role of ${E}_{t}$ vs. j?

Comment: I did not estimate those roles directly, instead I tried another way: I found Jefimenko's equations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations), which, if I am not wrong, are general solutions of Maxwell equations. On this site, I checked the equation for magnetic field and realized that the term containing time derivative of current (dJ/dt) is much smaller than the other term (with my data). Then I realized that I can approximate the so-called "retarded time" with regular time. This lefts us with time-dependent version of Biot-Savart law. However, I am not sure in my approach.

Comment: That looks right but I would go directly from Maxwell's equations, those are more fundamental. Do we know the current, electric field, time scales? It would be useful if you could add a sketch of your device showing characteristic dimensions etc.

Comment: I do know the maximal values of the current and its time derivative + the approximate time length of the current pulse, obtained after discharging from capacitor. I will edit my question tommorow, when I will have time for this.